# Shopify Custom Payment Gateway Implementation

Tags: php, payment-gateway, shopify

I successfully added my payment gateway to admin and its also show me on checkout page but when user click on "place order" i don't have any idea about how shopify process after that. i want to make payment using custom payment gateway.

Where i can add my custom file for payment gateway ? Or where i can add code for custom payment gateway.
what i need to do is..
- when user click on "place order" button ,get all the detail of order
- setup curl request for payment based on details

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [hosted-payments](https://github.com/Shopify/hosted-payment-sim) feature of Shopify.

This is where payment gateways can implement their payment processing with Shopify checkout.

You have to create a public page / website where Shopify will redirect after click on "place order" button.

There on this page/website you can have all order details and implement the gateway using curl requests etc.

More info you can find at [Hosted Payment SDK](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/hosted-payment-sdk) where you can see an Api reference for Request and Response values.

Comment: Thank u @Whiteulver. your ans will helpful for my app development. you mentioned public page do you mean shopify page ? and i can add code in that page template   ..right ? i want to create app for shopify store

Comment: I am not aware how Shopify apps works. If you are able to write any server side code on a Shopify app then maybe it is suitable. 
By public page i mean a page hosted by you, probably with ssl enabled and a PCI compliant certification.