# shopify custom payment gateway integration

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to integrate a custom payment gateway in shopify.Shopify by default was supporting [hosted payment sdk](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/hosted-payment-sdk) but now they We are no longer accepting new integrations.

Is there any other way in shopify.

Note there is already [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695481/shopify-custom-payment-gateway-implementation) related to my Question. But shopify no longer accepting new integration.

Thanks in advance